# localStorage Как результат счетчиков сделать на всех страницах одинаковым?

Tags: localstorage

```
        let dataCheck = document.querySelector('[data-check]');



    window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        const one = document.querySelector('[data-red]');
        let subcheckRed = document.querySelector('.subcheck__red'); 


        if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-red')) {        
    
            dataCheck.innerText = parseInt(dataCheck.innerText) + 1;
            subcheckRed.innerText = parseInt(subcheckRed.innerText) + parseInt(one.innerText);      
        }
    });

     document.querySelectorAll('[data-red]').forEach(el => {
       el.onclick = function() { this.classList.add('none'); };
    **Понимаю что надо вписать в код localStarage но не справляюсь.**});
```

Answer (score 0):

Помещайте в хранилище с помощью `localStorage.setItem('counter', parseInt(dataCheck.innerText))` свой счётчик. А читать/получать -

```
let counter = localStorage.getItem('counter')
dataCheck.innerText = counter;
```

P.S. использовал dataCheck.innerText, подразумевая, что это тот самый счётчик.

Comment: Огромная благодарность и уважуха за урок добавил counter++ и вроде заработало